# Why the data didn't contain in the list after i send it into a fucntion?

Tags: flutter

I'm studying flutter and praciting http request. My app send a request to the local server and contain the data into the list.

```
List data = [];
  displayMenu(List data) async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.http("10.0.2.2:3000", "api/menu"));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
      return data;
    }
  }
  displayMenu(data);
```

when i run the code, the data successfully contain into the list

```
/flutter ( 5148): [{menu_id: 101, category_id: 1, menu: Plain, price: 350}, {menu_id:
 102, category_id: 1, menu: Bulgogi, price: 380}, {menu_id: 103, category_id: 1, menu:
 Spicy, price: 390}, {menu_id: 104, category_id: 1, menu: 100g Chicken fillet, price: 
400}, {menu_id: 201, category_id: 2, menu: Beef bulgogi, price: 499}, {menu_id: 202, 
category_id: 2, menu: Jeyuk bokkuem, price: 450}, {menu_id: 203, category_id: 2, menu: 
Kamja tang, price: 599}, {menu_id: 204, category_id: 2, menu: Pork kalbi jjim, price: 
499}, {menu_id: 301, category_id: 3, menu: Spicy chicken wings, price: 185}, {menu_id: 
302, category_id: 3, menu: Fried chicken neck, price: 95}, {menu_id: 303, category_id: 3,
 menu: Fried chicken bucket, price: 340}, {menu_id: 304, category_id: 3, menu: Spicy 
fried chicken bucket, price: 380}, {menu_id: 305, category_id: 3, menu: Fried chicken 
skin, price: 11}, {menu_id: 401, category_id: 4, menu: Gizzard fried, price: 95}, 
{menu_id: 402, category_id: 4, menu: Gizzard spicy, price: 120}, {menu_id: 403, 
category_id: 4, m...
```

But if i change the print(data) out of the function,

```
List data = [];
  displayMenu(List data) async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.http("10.0.2.2:3000", "api/menu"));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      //print(data);
      return data;
    }
  }
  displayMenu(data);
  print(data);
```

The data didn't contained in the List and it appear empty on the console log

```
I/flutter ( 5148): []
Reloaded 1 of 643 libraries in 729ms.
```

How could I save the data in the list after the function ended?

Comment: please read [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) - they show how to get a result from an `async` method, if you are familiar with `Future`s you can skip some part and start from [Working with futures: async and await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await)

Answer (score 0):

this happens because the print after displayMenu(data) executes the initial value of the list. If you want to save data in list try with something like

```
 displayMenu(List data) async {
        var response = await http.get(Uri.http("10.0.2.2:3000", "api/menu"));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          data = jsonDecode(response.body);
          //print(data);
          data.addAll(response.body) or data.add(response.body)
          return data;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Future  displayMenu() async {
    
        List _data =[];
    
        var response = await http.get(Uri.http("10.0.2.2:3000", "api/menu"));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          data = jsonDecode(response.body);
          //print(data);
          
        }
    
       print(_data);
       return _data;
     
      }
```

Then call the function.

```
displayMenu(["A","B","C"]);
```

Comment: Yes . Depend on wish . But better to specification. Otherwise, it will take Future<dynamic>.

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<List<dynamic>>displayMenu() async {
  var response = await http.get(Uri.http("10.0.2.2:3000", "api/menu"));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return List<dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }
}
List<dynamic> data = await displayMenu(data);
print(data);
```

Instead of dynamic you can put String, int etc.
If you want to map an object, you may want to consider the map function.